Why "save" button is disabled in WSO2 APIM Publisher at Runtime tab.? In some APIs button is disabled
In some APIs button is disabled, but in other APIs button is enabled.
Apim version is 4.1
WSO2 API Manager, Publisher, one API, Runtime Tab.

Do you have any solution to enable it?

Mu question is important. some APIs have enabled "save" button but some others do not have.

When you select Restrict by role(s) from Developer Portal Visibility and you don't write anything in the Roles section I don't know why but the SAVE button in Runtime is disabled!


Thank you. it solved my problem. but sometimes cannot add role and we got error! Is this known to you?!

Let me explain the API creation workflow here. When you are creating an API from the publisher, we identify your changes and category them into two sections called runtime configuration and portal configuration. The portal configurations are mainly known as the changes that you need to do when publishing your API into the API marketplace or a devportal. The runtime configurations are the changes that go to the gateway runtime.
So when you make any change to the API and trying to deploy those changes to the API gateway, we are letting user to create a revision in order to deploy those changes to the gateway. The idea here is that, you can rollback to your previous revision if there is any issue with the existing revision. This is somewhat similar to having a version history for your gateway related changes of the API.
You can see a drop down next to the name of the API (1) . There you can see drop down item as 'Current API'. This is your working copy. You can do any changes on top of this and create revisions.
From the drop down, you can select any revision number as you can see in the image (2). This shows a read only window and that is why you see a disabled save button in this window.
(1) - 
(2) - 
